# Python curses not showing certain characters

Tags: python, font-awesome, curses

This may be a question better suited for UNIX stack exchange but thought I would post here as I do not know what exactly the problem is. I have a python script that uses curses and displays characters from font awesome 5 free. This script worked fine, but just recently I reinstalled my os and now it is not displaying these characters. The terminal I am using is capable of displaying the character on the cli, python is able to print the character, it is only when it is echoed through curses that it does not display. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

More information:
Here is a mock up of the script:

```
import curses
from curses import wrapper

def main(stdscr):
  while True:
    stdscr.addstr(0,0,STRING)
    stdscr.refresh()

wrapper(main)
```

when STRING is something like "a", "b", or "cat" it shows up fine. However when the character is something like "" or "" it does not display anything.

Comment: Please provide enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KlausD. Edited post with more information.

Comment: You have not even named your OS, encoding, Python version...

Comment: @KlausD. Arch Linux, utf-8, python 3.8.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode Box Drawing characters not printed in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429607/unicode-box-drawing-characters-not-printed-in-ruby)